# Calling javascript multiple times causes setInterval to never be cleared

Tags: javascript, scope, callback, setinterval

I am loading images into the DOM

The function that loads the image sets and interval and checks for the image to be loaded completely before executing another function that changes the images color.

When the document loads I execute this function 4 times(4 different images) and this is resulting in the interval never being cleared on at least one of the images sometimes multiple.

the function:

```
function setCloth(clothImg, prefix){
    $('#'+prefix+'_cloth_div').html('<img class="" id="'+prefix+'_clothImg" src="/figures/'+clothImg+'" />');
    cloth = prefix+'Cloth';
    imageSource[cloth] = '/figures/'+clothImg;

    checkClothInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if (document.getElementById(prefix+"_clothImg").complete){
              console.log('skin image complete');
              changeCloth(prefix, 'Cloth', '#ffffff');
              //====================================================
              //somehow this is not reached on a couple of the image loads
              //====================================================
              clearInterval(checkClothInterval);
          }else{
              console.log('skin image not complete');
          }
    }, 100);

}
```

Is it variable scope or something?

Comment: Use the [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword for local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it variable scope or something?

Yes, you're not using `var` to declare your variables so they are all global, and you only have one `checkClothInterval` (a global) instead of one for each interval. Use [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) every time you declare a variable:

```
function setCloth(clothImg, prefix){
    $('#'+prefix+'_cloth_div').html('<img class="" id="'+prefix+'_clothImg" src="/figures/'+clothImg+'" />');
    var cloth = prefix+'Cloth';
    imageSource[cloth] = '/figures/'+clothImg;

    var checkClothInterval = setInterval(function(){
        if (document.getElementById(prefix+"_clothImg").complete){
              console.log('skin image complete');
              changeCloth(prefix, 'Cloth', '#ffffff');
              clearInterval(checkClothInterval);
          }else{
              console.log('skin image not complete');
          }
    }, 100);

}
```

Comment: wow.. all this time I thought var in front made it global.. TIL! Thanks

Comment: @silversunhunter Ah, you had it backwards. `var` makes it local to the current execution context; without `var` a new variable is implicitly global. You're welcome.